# how do I track down a file that is in ResolveAssemblyReference.cache but isn't in a sln or csproj?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a solution that includes a reference to an assembly (Assembly R). In Assembly R, there was a reference to two SharpSvn related assemblies that were not needed. So I took those references out of Assembly R and rebuilt it. Now, in my sln that references Assembly R, when I build, I'm getting:

```
Unable to copy file "C:\Dev\...\bin\SharpSvn-DB44-20-Win32.dll" to \
"bin\Debug\SharpSvn-DB44-20-Win32.dll". Could not find file 
'C:\Dev\...\bin\SharpSvn-DB44-20-Win32.dll'.
```

So I looked through all of the files in my project directory for any references to these files. The only place they are found is in some dll's and in two files in obj: **FileListAbsolute.txt** and **ResolveAssemblyReference.cache**. So I wiped the obj folder and rebuilt. Still the builder is attempting to copy these files. But in Assembly R there are no references to these files and I've rebuilt my reference to Assembly R. So there's some sort of caching going on, I suppose, but I don't know where.

Where should I look next?

Comment: Check the project folder is in read only mode?. Please right click and see the properties, if it is in read only mode then un check and try to build.

Comment: @Sudharshanan sorry I don't have this code around any more, can't answer

Answer (score 0):

Where does ResolveAssemblyReference.cache say it's obtaining the copy of your assembly file?  That's probably the location with the outdated copy.  When you regenerate ResolveAssemblyReference.cache, it will still try to find preexisting copies of the assembly file, so if you have not removed the outdated copy, ResolveAssemblyReference.cache will still use it.